# Emulating the CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE function in SQL or Python

Tags: floating-point, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, abap, sap-erp

Inside my Snowflake we are using sap tables as data source, in one of our SAP tables we have values stored in the format `0x1.34b049p24` which equals `02/17/2023`.

Now the problem is in Snowflake I am only having the float value, which is the first value I mentioned. Now I need to do a transformation to get to the date value. I got told that this is accomplished by using the `CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE` function in SAP ERP. Now I do not know how to accomplish this in Snowflake as there is not an equivalent function. Can someone explain how that function works to emulate it in some kind of way? Or point me to a recourse I could use.

Thank you very much.

I was not able to find any other information regarding this function.

Comment: Hi - as that value is not a float it seems unlikely a function that converts floats to dates would work. Can you provide any more information on what that value actually is? Have you confirmed that SAP can convert this value to to the date you’ve given?

Comment: Hi NickW, 
Yes it was confirmed that these values are used in SAP and converted via the CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE funciton. How did you determine that the value i've provided is not a float? My knowledge about SAP is quite limited, i just know that this is the abap function used to make these calculations to retrieve the date format

Comment: I don’t believe it is a float because I’m unaware of any representation of a float where the character ‘p’ would be valid. However, I have no issue with someone proving me wrong

Comment: In any case, my suggestion would be to get SAP to convert these values as part of the extraction process, rather than trying to reverse engineer it once the data has been landed in Snowflake

Comment: No need to know "SAP" (in fact it's ABAP): `0x` means it's followed by hexadecimal digits `0` to `9` and `a` to `f`, and there shouldn't be neither `.` nor `p`. 10 hex digits mean 5 bytes and it represents nothing in "SAP". You have to tell us how you get this weird value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did some googling and this is what I came up with.

`0x` is used in code to indicate that the number is being written in hex.

suffix `p24` indicates that the number is multiplied by 2^24.

`1.34b049` hex value in decimal format is `1.20581489801406860352`.

When `1.20581489801406860352` is multiplied with `2^24 (16777216)`, you get `20230217` which is the `date` you are looking for.

I don't think the above calculation has anything to do with SAP function module **CTCV_CONVERT_FLOAT_TO_DATE**

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be it :)

Comment: @yavuz Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. This helps to keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.